# Find unique occurrence at the end of the string JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I recieve the following strings

```
str = "Something happened in NewYork";
str1 = "New";
```

The thing is that I need a function that can tell me if `str1` is at the end of the `str` and I can have the case in which `str` doesn't contain at all `str1.`
So in this case the function should return false because `str1` still has characters after it.

I used `str.includes(" "+str1)` but I don't think i can tell this function to look at only at the end of my string.
So what can I use ? ( and how? ).

Comment: Well, you know the length of your str1.  You could always substring the same number of characters off the end of str for your comparison

Comment: Soo you are trying to see if a string [ends with](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith) another string?

Comment: Well yeah but then I'd have one more operation to do and it would slow down performance .Because it is at the end of the string i think the most efficient thing would be a function that can check the occurence of ur string and if it has any characters after it or not . It would be so nice If I could use something like str+NULL or something inside my function.

Comment: Yes Ivar .And if it is possible I would need a function for this.

Comment: please define *end of string*. is the example a valid end of string?

Comment: Did you look at the link that I subtly placed in my comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `substr()` with a negative number to get the last `n` characters from the end of a string.

```js
var strA = "Something happened in NewYork";
var strB = "Something happened in New";
var str1 = "New";

console.log(str1 === strA.substr(-str1.length));
console.log(str1 === strB.substr(-str1.length));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [endsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith)

```js
const str = "Something happened in NewYork";
const str1 = "New";
const str2 = "York";

console.log( str.endsWith(str1) )
console.log( str.endsWith(str2) )
```